# How to set up firefox to only look up address bar pop-down hint bookmarks in specific folders?

Tags: bookmarks, firefox

By default today Firefox versions use whole bookmarks and history databases to suggest items in a drop-down list when I write an URL manually.

I'd like to limit the suggestions base with just some (or one) specific folders in my bookmarks. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can *selectively* disable bookmark folders, but turning off autocomplete from bookmarks *completely* is possible via ***browser.urlbar.default.behavior*** configuration parameter. You can read more on this [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.urlbar.default.behavior).

Comment: What I actually want to achieve is a manually-set list of urls for this lookup.